# Conditional search in django filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filters

I want to retrieve some data from my database in this way

```py
from .models import Student

#activity is a many to many field

students = Student.objects.filter(name="doe",activity__name__icontains='a' or 'b').distinct().all()
```

This will work .

But my problem is I have a list of items to check against the activities and if I try it like this ... it fails

```
activities = ['a','b','c']
students = Student.objects.filter(name="doe",activity__name__icontains=activities).distinct().all()
```

The length of the list is not constant it always varies.

I would appreciate any helping hand.

Thank you

Comment: The first one does not work, it will never match with things that do not contain `'a'`, but contain `'b'`. The `or` will inspect the truthiness of `'a'`, and thus never take `'b'` into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one does not work, it will never match with things that do not contain `'a'`, but contain `'b'`. The `or` will inspect the truthiness of `'a'`, and thus never take `'b'` into account.

As for the list, you can work with a `Q` object here:

```
from django.db.models import Q

activities = ['a','b','c']
activity_filter = Q(
    *[('activity__name__icontains',activity) for activity in activities],
    _connector=Q.OR
)

students = Student.objects.filter(activity_filter, name='doe').distinct()
```

Comment: According to your explanation. I agree that my first method won't work.
But one question I am getting an error on this line when I try to implement this,  _connector=Q.OR

Comment: @SteveMitto: what error do you get? Did you put an asterisk in fron of the list comprehension?

Comment: @SteveMitto: sorry, there is a comma missing and the end of the list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working well. 
Appreciated.